# Azure Service Fabric Reverse Proxy on Local Cluster

Tags: localhost, reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

I am currently experimenting the Naming Service resolution on my 5-nodes local cluster and encountering some resistance :). Here is the deal:

- My Local Cluster Manifest defines an endpoint & protocol for the Reverse Proxy on each "fake" node. The entry is HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint.
- If I browse through the explorer on port 19080, I can find my running Stateless Service (Kestrel Swagger API) at this URL: http://localhost:8145/7303da82-4ed2-4548-996d-1b5e8f49c7c9/131574695524899694/swagger/
- If I try to use the Reverse Proxy Gateway with the service full-name I get:

http://localhost:19081/SHRec.SF.App/SHRec.SF.Front.ClientAPI/swagger

Which gets translated to:

http://localhost:19081/7303da82-4ed2-4548-996d-1b5e8f49c7c9/131574695524899694/swagger/

Where one can detect that the port is incorrect for a direct connection and that normally one should not be able to see the internal address...

Any Idea ?

Best :)

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? When calling internal services through the built-in reverse proxy, you always use the port at which the reverse proxy listens.

Comment: Well yes, maybe it is obvious but I tried it exactly as described:

1) use port 19081 (ApplicationGatewayEndpoint => ReverseProxy)

2) The resolved address is correct but the service is not reached

3) If I try to change the port to the phisical underlying addres (8145 -> Node 4) Then it works

So it must be a misconfiguration on the routing somewhere... Moreover I believe that the displayed address in the browser shouldn't be the "physical" one, at least not the GUID that is presented but the logical version "AppName/ServiceName... etc"

Comment: Be aware that it is a local cluster, not an on premises installation nor the Cloud Service.

Comment: Do you run on win10 /server 2016?

Comment: Well, solved it... Just add a "/" after the first URL and it works like a charm... Jesus Christ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cf last comment, everything runs smoothly locally and on the Cloud :)

Comment: Could you please edit this answer to include your above comment? That will make it useful to other people. :-)